# Program Output Problems (Java)

Tags: java

I was given an assignment to write a program which will accept any number of input data until 999 has been read. Then the program should type out total number of zero's and various other requests, but the problem is I don't know the output command to tell it to read the number of zeros. All I have so far is

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
 public class MidtermI {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numbers = console.nextInt();
```

and then from there I'm lost.

Comment: Start here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html Then try here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create ArrayList to hold the zero values the print its size.

```
ArrayList<Integer> zeroValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Then loop n time to input n numbers:

```
for(int i=0; i<999; i++) {
    int numbers = console.nextInt();
    if(number == 0) {
        zeroValues.add(number);
    }
}
```

Then you could print the total of zero's values like:

```
System.out.println(zeroValues.size());
```

Comment: Thanks, I never used an array list so I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

Break it down into small steps, and check that each step works before going further:

The first thing you need to sort out is to be able to read multiple inputs, by looping. Your current code only reads a single number from the `Scanner`.

Next, you need to check for the special value 999, and stop looping when that is received.

When you have got that working, figure out how to count the zeros - either by counting them as they arrive, or collecting all the values and counting them afterwards.

You can then print out the required results using `System.out.println()` - but you'll probably want to use that for testing and debugging your code as you go along, anyway.

Comment: Thoroughly helpful post, without spoon-feeding.  Very nice!